# How to disable Vim freezing on Windows

Tags: vim, text-editor

I started using Vim actively and as any Windows user I came across problem subconsciously pressing `CTRL + S` which freezes the screen for some time (at least it seems so). I read different pages on how to exit this mode. It seems that `CTRL + Q` or `CTRL + S` help, but it's not a solution. I read that there's a possibility to disable this mode at all, but most of the suggestions concern Linux. How do I do it on Windows?

Comment: My compatibility knowledge isn't great try `CTRL-c` or `CTRL-g` which varioulsy work to interrupt processes sometimes on windows.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with programming or Linux or Windows or even Vim, which doesn't even handle that key combination to begin with.

`CTRL-S` is usually handled by your terminal emulator for [flow control](http://osr600doc.xinuos.com/en/SDK_sysprog/_TTY_Flow_Control.html) and if that's the case, `CTRL-Q` as well. If you want that feature disabled, you will have to do it at a lower level, either in your terminal emulator's options or in your shell config file but you didn't mention your terminal emulator or your shell so you are on your own, now.

Comment: I'm using ConEmu terminal emulator.